# Maven dependency for the CXF

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I am using Maven for my Java project and getting this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/logging/FaultListener
```

I think I need to include the maven dependency for the above.I have posted the code snippet from **pom.xml** below.

```
          <properties>          
                  <cxf.version>2.5.2</cxf.version>          
          </properties>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-xml</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

I am not very much comfortable with Maven.Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

This class is in `org.apache.cxf:cxf-api`. Other cxf artifacts such as cxf-rt-transports-http have this as a dependency, so you *should* have this already.

Is a cxf-api jar included when you build your project?

Comment: What is your cxf-api jar version inside your war ?